# The Collection Cipher

Tags: cipher

This is a repost from my puzzle blog. (Link in my profile.)

[image: The Collection Cipher]

My great uncle from Atlanta died last month, and my family drove there to attend the funeral and prepare his house for an estate sale.

When I was cleaning his office, I found a strange note.  I’ve stared at it for hours, and I just can’t figure out what it means. Maybe you can help. I am attaching a copy at actual size.

The note wasn’t the only strange thing in his office. Every square inch was filled with Coca Cola memorabilia — posters, newspaper ads, toys, and unopened bottles.  By far his largest collection was of 12 oz. Coke cans from different eras. There must have been hundreds!  And apparently when he wrote the note, he was thirsty. On the desk beside the note was an empty Coke can, the only empty can in the room.

Other than the Coke memorabilia, the room looked like a typical office. On his desk were pencils, a spiral notebook, a cloth tape measure, Scotch tape, and a pair of scissors, though I doubt most of this has anything to do with the note.

Maybe it’s all just gibberish, or maybe there’s more than meets the eye. Can you help me solve the mystery?

Hint:

> I get the sense that the first step is printing out a physical copy of the note at actual size. I added the "1 inch" marker, so you can be sure it is scaled correctly when printed. That is the marker's sole purpose.

Hint 2:

> See the white squares at the bottom? I get the sense that you use these to fill in a 5-letter keyword, which serves as a way to reorder something. There are some numbers in the image, and I feel like these, in conjunction with the Coke clues, may help you find that keyword.

Notes on sizing:

> For those without access to a 12 oz. U.S. soda can, its diameter is 65.75mm or 2.588 inches. For the 1 inch scale, 1 inch equals 25.4 mm.

[image]

Comment: I deliberately didn't add a text version because I am trying to steer people into solving by the intended method, which involves printing the image.

Comment: "Please consider the environment before printing out this puzzle."

Comment: Well, it's only one 8.5" x 11"  page. You could take an already-used sheet and print on the back of it.

Comment: @TonyYoungblood i don't think MOehm was being serious :)

Comment: Oh gotcha. It seemed in earnest but I am famous for reading things wrong.

Comment: "I am the Oehm-ax, I speak for the trees"

Comment: Seems like a scytale to me. Wrap it around the coke can and a message should appear. Can't be bothered to print it out and do it myself though I'm a little busy

Comment: @Quadraxus, interesting...

Comment: At first I wondered if it should be wrapped around the can as is, but if I've multiplied the sizes up correctly (I'm neither in a position to print out the image right now, nor do I have access to a US sized coke can, so I googled the diameter and muliplied by pi), the length of the image is a couple of inches too long to wrap snugly around the diameter of the can. Maybe it's supposed to be cut into 5 strips joined together end-to-end, then wrapped round the can in a spiral? Trying to simulate this in software didn't seem to lead to anything through... but I didn't try re-ordering the strips.

Comment: FWIW I've tried (in software, no actual printing) spiral-wrapping with the strips joined in the obvious order and in reverse order, and not found anything very obvious. The circumference of the can is (I think, going off internet info on the size of a 12-oz US Coke can) rather close to 16 2/3 letters; this doesn't change much if you offset the strips enough to make a spiral.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve and Gareth. I added a hint that may help.

Comment: Keyword is probably Frank, the logo was made in 5/8/1886 and Frank coined the name so I reckon we do the scytale and then Vignere with frank probably, unless you just ceasar shift the individual strips by their letter

Comment: Once again I can't really be bothered to print it out, eh maybe later when I'm free

Comment: Oh @Gareth mind sharing your results?

Comment: Keyword is not Frank.

Comment: Hmm. Johns as in john S is my 2nd guess, can't be loci or script....

Comment: After checking a bit more Stith is probably it although it could be drink

Comment: Think about something historic that happened on that date and where it happened. (More specific than the city.)

Comment: "Stith" has 5 letters but one repeated letter, so it wouldn't work great for a 5 character reordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first clue is the obsession with Coca-Cola. The only

> numbers in the note are 188658. Or, 1886-5-8 - May 8th, 1886. This is the date Coca-Cola was first sold.

With some investigation, we find this

> happened at Jacob's pharmacy. Putting the name Jacob at the bottom in the blank squares, and then ordering by alphabetical order, tells us that column 2 comes first, then 5, 3, 1 and 4. This is consistent with the numbers in column 4 being tacked on at the end of the message.

If you print the message out,

> cut into columns, arrange in this order, and then wrap around the Coke can (found on the desk next to the message) you find that every 17th letter (remember to start counting from 1, 18, 35, ...) is displayed vertically.

[Here's what it looks like wrapped around a can.](https://codeaweek.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/20171021_211137.jpg)

Read them in this manner and ignore the numerals to find out the message says:

> THENEWANDPOPULARSODAFOUNTAINDRINKCONTAININGTHEPROPERTIESOFTHEWONDERFULCOCAPLANTANDTHEFAMOUSCOLANUTS

That is:

> The new and popular soda fountain drink containing the properties of the wonderful coca plant and the famous cola nuts

Which is:

> A line from an early Coca Cola advertisement, back when it contained cocaine.

[Picture](https://codeaweek.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/early-coke-ad.jpg)

The items on the desk...

> ...are clues. You need a pencil to write the codeword, scissors to cut the note into strips, and Scotch tape to tape them together. “Spiral notebook” hinted that you had to make a spiral, and “cloth tape measure” hinted that you needed to wrap something around something else.

Schematic summary:

> ```
>   j: LDMOTEOSUDOIPTTDCATOL         a: TAUDTITGOEERCTEUA HNLA         TAUDTITGOEERCTEUA
>   a: TAUDTITGOEERCTEUAHNLA         b: ANATPSWFAAFSN EDAFIKIH         HNLAANATPSWFAAFSN
>   c: EOOUPNACUNPRONCNERFNL  --->   c: EOOUPNACU NPRONCNERFNL  --->   EDAFIKIHEOOUPNACU
>   o: SWPONRNNRIHEONH188658         j: LDMOT EOSUDOIPTTDCATOL         NPRONCNERFNLLDMOT
>   b: ANATPSWFAAFSNEDAFIKIH         o: S WPONRNNRIHEONH188 658        EOSUDOIPTTDCATOLS
>                                                                      WPONRNNRIHEONH188
>                                                                      658
>                                                                               |
>    .--------------------------------------------------------------------------'
>    |
>    V
>
>      |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\   |\
>      | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \  | \
>    T |  A |  u |  d |  t |  i |  t |  g |  o |  e |  e |  r |  c |  t |  e |  u |  a
>    h |  n |  l |  a |  a |  n |  a |  T |  p |  s |  W |  f |  a |  A |  F |  s |  N
>    e |  d |  a |  F |  i |  k |  i |  h |  e |  O |  o |  u |  P |  n |  a |  C |  u
>    N |  P |  r |  o |  n |  C |  n |  e |  r |  f |  n |  l |  l |  d |  m |  o |  t
>    e |  o |  S |  u |  D |  o |  i |  P |  t |  T |  d |  C |  a |  T |  o |  l |  s
>    w |  p |  o |  n |  r |  n |  n |  r |  i |  h |  e |  o |  n |  h |   \|   \|
>     \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|   \|
> ```

Comment: Excellent work! You got everything right! The solution is a quote from an early Coca Cola ad. I'll post a picture above.

Comment: Eedrah, you are now in second place on the [CodeAWeek leaderboard](https://codeaweek.wordpress.com/high-scores/)!

Comment: Awesome! (I should have waited for a few more days ;) ) Is there a way to quickly view all of your unanswered questions? Are they all posted here on PSX, or are some kept only on your blog?

Comment: Yes. There are 3 unsolved puzzles, and you can view them all [here](https://codeaweek.wordpress.com/category/unsolved/). I have not posted these three on PSX yet.

Comment: Actually, I just [cross-posted Challenge 10 on PSX](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56264/no-cheating-cipher-challenge). I suspect it will be solved fairly quickly.